# Writing one column of an Array or transposing a 2 column array to a one column then writing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-finance

Hello I have tried to figure this out for many days and I just can't.  Can I lean on you guys for some help?

I am pulling 2 columns from a sheet into an array, then I am looping the array overwriting the second column of the array to become a SQL insert string.  Then I write the array to another sheet.  The trouble is I really only want to write column 2 of the array to the new sheet.  The first column is not needed and it actually occupies cells I need because the price history I am pulling puts the google sheet over the 5,000,000 cell limit.  If I can write only one column it won't go over the limit.

```
//this code is running in a loop returning each different stock in a list of tickers

//get 2 columns from the price history and put them in an array
  const PRICERANGE=SheetPriceHistory.getDataRange();
  var PRICEARRAY=PRICERANGE.getValues();

//append the output of the the entire array to the other sheet.  
SheetScript.getRange(SheetScript.getLastRow()+1,1,PRICEARRAY.length,PRICEARRAY[0].length).setValues(PRICEARRAY); 
// this is where I would like to write just column 2 of the array to the SheetScript sheet.
```

Comment: What is your array of which you want only the first column? PRICEARRAY?

Comment: Yes PRICEARRAY.   PRICEARRAY has 2 columns PRICEARRAY[0][0] and PRICEARRAY[0][1].  I only want to write PRICEARRAY[0][1] to SheetScript and I am trying to do it in one shoot so I can minimize read writes.  Is there a way to SwtValues(PRICEARRAY[0][1])?  I just don't know what features to use or syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Provided that your data is located in the columns A and B of the sheet `SheetPriceHistory`, you can retrieve the first column selectively

To do so, replace the request `getDataRange()` by [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Thereby `numColumns` will be `1` if you want to retrieve only one column and the number of rows can be retrieved with `getLastRow()`.

So:

```js
 const PRICERANGE=SheetPriceHistory.getRange(1, 1, SheetPriceHistory.getLastRow(), 1);
  var PRICEARRAY=PRICERANGE.getValues();

//append the output of the the entire array to the other sheet.  
SheetScript.getRange(SheetScript.getLastRow()+1,1,PRICEARRAY.length,PRICEARRAY[0].length).setValues(PRICEARRAY);
```

### UPDATE

If you want to retrieve a two column array and drop the first column later on, you can do it with [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Sample:

```js
  const PRICERANGE=SheetPriceHistory.getRange(1, 1, SheetPriceHistory.getLastRow(), 2);
  var PRICEARRAY=PRICERANGE.getValues();
  ... //do something
  //now overwrite the array with only the second column
  PRICEARRAY = PRICEARRAY.map(function (e) { 
    return [e[1]]; 
  })
  //append the output of the the entire array to the other sheet.  
  SheetScript.getRange(SheetScript.getLastRow()+1,1,PRICEARRAY.length,PRICEARRAY[0].length).setValues(PRICEARRAY);
```

Comment: Thank you that would work but there is just one issue.  I am using both column A and B to build the SQL string but then I only need to post the column with the insert string to SheetScript.  Is there  a way to do what you are proposing on the output instead of the input like SetValues(PriceArray[1])

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean with SQL string and insert string. If you build this string before assigning the values to `SheetScript` - can you show the relevant code and the structure of the string?

Comment: Sure this is the looped function here.  Its a 2 column array that is pulled from the first sheet then I loop it and overwrite column 2 with the SQL insert string.  After this is done I don't need column 1 anymore but I don't know how to write the array to SheetScript without writing both columns.
```
     PRICEARRAY[i][1]="INSERT INTO PRICE_HISTORY VALUES ('" + PRICEDATE + "','" + (TICKERARRAY[TICKERCOUNTER][0]) + "','" + String(PRICEARRAY[i][1]) + "')"; 
```

Comment: Nice I am totally going to try this I will let you know.  I did not know about map that looks useful

Comment: This totally worked I had to adjust the code to get through some syntax errors that I couldn't follow with my limited understanding of the script syntax but here is my final code using your map suggestion.

```
  const start = SheetScript.getLastRow()+1
  const length = SheetScript.getLastRow()+1 + PRICEARRAY2.length-1
  const range = ["A" + start.toString() + ":A" + length.toString()].join("");
  const fn = function(v) {
    return [ v ];
  };
  SheetScript.getRange(range).setValues(values.map(fn));
```

I don't even really understand what the code is doing but its working :)